# hide tabs in Access 2010 with vba

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I'm using Access 2010 and I'd like to hide the tabs, when the person is not admin. My admin variable is stored Temp Variable.

How can I do that?

Best regards

Matthias

Answer (score 0):

Hiding and showing the tabs (ie a tab for an open access object - ie a form, query, report, etc) is a setting for the current database project, that only takes effect once the database file is closed and re-opened.  Although the value can be set by code, it is not practical as it would apply to all users who then open the the file.  (and you would need to set it, close, repoen ...)

You might like to have two copies of the database front end file held on a server  with windows file permissions such that admin opens a different file to plebs, the admin file  shows the tabs and other users open a file that doesn't.

Comment: Which is the VBA code to show/hide object tabs?